# Eclipse Javadoc formatting: how to allow/disallow single-line Javadoc comments?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc, code-formatting

So, random question:

I've got a codebase where lots of enums, etc have comments that look like this:

```
public enum SomeEnum {
  /** value1 */
  VALUE1,
  /** value2 */
  VALUE2;
}
```

Is there a way to compel the Eclipse formatter to break up the Javadocs into a "standard" multi-line format, like the below?  My current settings have no effect on the above snippet.

```
public enum SomeEnum {
  /**
   * value1
   */
  VALUE1,
  /**
   * value2
   */
  VALUE2;
}
```

The current behavior doesn't do this - running Eclipse 4.4.0, with the following checked in Javadoc comment settings:

```
(X) Format HTML tags
(X) Format Java code snippets inside 'pre' tags
(X) Blank line before Javadoc tags
(X) Indent Javadoc tags
  ( ) Indent description after @param
( ) New line after @param tags
(X) /** and */ on separate lines
( ) Remove blank lines
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is one of many bugs with eclipse's code formatter for comments (including Javadoc). You should open a bug report [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/).

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround:** Open the `Find/Replace` (<kbd>ctrl+F</kbd>) and put `\Q/**\E` into the `Find` field and `/**\R` into the `Replace with` field. Then click `Replace All`. Once this has been done activate your formatter and it should format it the way you want. (What you are doing is adding a new line at the beginning of each Javadoc comment, which compels the formatter to use multi-line formatting.)

Answer (score 0):

Failure of the formatter to move `/**` and `*/` to different lines can be caused by the *Formatter → Comments → General Settings → Never join lines* box being checked.

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but that box is blank in my settings.